# Paperclip error when uploading video: can't dump File

Tags: ruby-on-rails, video, paperclip

When I try to upload a video using `Paperclip`, I get an error message `can't dump File`.

Model `Video` :

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
has_attached_file :avatar,
   :storage => :s3,
   :styles => {
     :mp4 => { :geometry => "640x480", :format => 'mp4' },
     :thumb => { :geometry => "300x300>", :format => 'jpg', :time => 5 }
   }, :processors => [:ffmpeg]

  validates_attachment_presence :avatar

  validates_attachment_content_type :avatar,
   :content_type => /video/,
   :message => "Video not supported"

end
```

Comment: what error? Can you copy and then gracefully paste the error message for the people to see?

Comment: i get error : "can't dump File", when try to create video. The attachment from papercipt can't save to database

Comment: Can you paste the entire message dump? All lines of it?

Comment: can't dump File

Rails.root: /home/my_name/Projects/ss
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

Request

Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"PZ1WKfzlnoY60S8V0IMeIsHEmo2sfsh7ktHmTrKluFc=",
 "video"=>{"avatar"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0xfc62ac8 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20140613-18854-lvmma3>,
 @original_filename="captcha bug.mp4",
 @content_type="video/mp4",
 @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"video[avatar]\"; filename=\"captcha bug.mp4\"\r\nContent-Type: video/mp4\r\n">},
 "event_id"=>"1"}

Comment: i'm stuck here, please help me

Comment: Please!!!!! Check your log/development.log (if you are running development mode) file and see the stack trace... Then, edit your question and paste it as code. This would be really helpful!